# CUDA programming problem 3

Tags: cuda

I have two one dimensional array. Now I have to perform 'anding' these two arrays, if the elements of the arrays are equal, then I have to put the element in a 2d array.

I've written the following code, but my code is not working. Can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#define height 3
#define width 2

__global__ void fun(unsigned char *c ,unsigned short *s,unsigned char *u,size_t pitch)
{ 

    int tid =blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
    //int tidy=blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y ;

    if(tid<6)
    {

        for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r)
        {        //float* row = (float*)((char*)u + r*pitch);

                for (int d = 0; d< width; ++d) 
                {
                    u[r*width+d] = c[tid] & s[tid];
                }
        }
    } 
}


int main()
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned char man[6]="manis",*dev_c,jan[3][2],*dev_r;

    unsigned short a[6]={32,33,43,35,36,37},*dev_s;

    size_t pitch;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c,sizeof( unsigned char)*6);       // memory allocation on device

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_s,sizeof(unsigned short)*6);

    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_r, &pitch, width*sizeof(unsigned char),height);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_c,man, 6*sizeof(unsigned char),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_s,a, 6*sizeof(short int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    fun<<<5,2>>>(dev_c,dev_s,dev_r,pitch);

    cudaMemcpy2D(jan,3*sizeof(unsigned char),dev_r,pitch,sizeof( unsigned char),2,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\nThe call is completd");

    for ( i=0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < height; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",jan[j+i*width]);
        }
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I used *cudamallocpitch* to allocate 2d on device then I use *cudamemcpy* to copy the array back on host, but the code is not working properly every time a run it it shows all new values.

Can any body explain me how to achieve my goal which is "anding the elements of 2 one dimentional array and put the result in 2d".

Please ignore my english and help me.

Comment: You haven't said what isn't working. What is the exact problem you are having? And please give your questions meaningful titles, how does this title help anyone?

Comment: Completely agree with talonmies. Please give your posts descriptive titles. You're giving all your posts these generic titles which don't say anything about the specific question you're having.

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong with this code, it is almost impossible to compose a reasonable answer. However, in no particular order I can see the following:

1. You have multiple buffer overflows in device memory, mostly stemming from using 25 threads to write into arrays with either 4 or 5 words allocated
2. Your kernel contains a terrible memory race. Threads will be overwriting oneanother's outputs, which give undefined behaviour in CUDA.
3. The while loop in your kernel will
   produce infinite looping behavior
   and the kernel may never terminate
   as a result.
4. You keep asking about 2D arrays, but
   nowhere in you code is a 2D array.
   Everything is linear 1D memory from
   what I can see.

That should keep you busy for a while.

---

EDIT: another day, another completely different version of the code, so some more comments:

1. Your kernel is now completely serial. The first 6 threads will all attempt to overwrite the output array with different results. This is a memory race.
2. Your are mixing `char` and `unsigned short` data types inside the kernel. That probably means you are performing the and operation between an 8 and 16 bit values, then storing the result in an 8 bit type. Even without the memory race, I am fairly sure this is not what you want.
3. For about the **tenth time**, I will repeat myself - `cudaMallocPitch` allocates linear memory with padding to make it a good size for the GPU memory controller and texture units. It is not allocating 2D arrays. So if you want to access that linear memory, you need to use the pitch returned by the `cudaMallocPitch` call. The formula for accessing the memory is in the [documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g80d689bc903792f906e49be4a0b6d8db.html), but I will repeat it here:

   `T* pElement = (T*)((char*)BaseAddress + Row * pitch) + Column;`
4. Every API call in your program returns an error code. You should check every one of them to see whether any runtime errors are being detected.

Comment: hi Now i changed my code my code is working now . but still unpridicatable behavior please explain me about this behavior the code will be in next comment . one thing i want to say I'm using cudamallock pitch and treating dev_r as my 2d on gpu. please enlightened me more on this issue coz there nothing much is written about this topic . In my next comment you will get the new code which is performing "and " operation over array element and putting them into one 2-d array. please tell me my  logical mistakes and their solution . This will help me to understand the concept of cuda

Comment: __global__ void fun(unsigned char *c ,unsigned short *s,unsigned char *r){int tid =blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
int tidy=blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y ;
if(tid<6){r[tid*2+tidy]=c[tid]&s[tid];}}
int main(){int i,j;unsigned char man[6]="manis",*dev_c,jan[3][2],*dev_r;unsigned short a[6]={32,33,43,35,36,37},*dev_s;
size_t pitch;cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c,sizeof( unsigned char)*6);

Comment: the remaining code cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_s,sizeof(unsigned short)*6);
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_r, &pitch, 2*sizeof(unsigned char),3);
cudaMemcpy(dev_c,man,6*sizeof(unsignedchar),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_s,a, 6*sizeof(short int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
fun<<<5,2>>>(dev_c,dev_s,dev_r);cudaMemcpy2D(jan,2*sizeof(unsigned char),dev_r,pitch,sizeof( unsigned char),2,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
for(i=0;i<3;i++){for(j=0;j<2;j++){printf ("\t%d",jan[j][i]);}}
return 0;}

Comment: please help this novice fellow

Comment: Edit your question to reflect the code changes and what the remaining problems are. Those comments are completely unreadable as it. You are running the risk that this question will get closed just like your last one did.